# Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio is disabled and won't enable

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I had Productivity Power Tools (PPT) installed on my Visual Studio 2012 for quite some time and everything was working well. Suddenly, it stopped working and I noticed it got disabled under Extensions.

I cannot enable it (the Enable button is grayed out), only uninstall, but even uninstalling it and re-installing it didn't do the trick!

I also installed VS 2013 Community (the new full free version) and installed PPT on it and the situation is exactly the same.

Comment: Did yiu install any other extensions? Then try to remove these..

Comment: Obviously, I do have other extensions installed, but there hasn't been any change in them adjacent to the time this issue started. In addition, I have another computer (work) where everything is working fine, so I went over the installed extensions and got them both to be pretty much the same, so I doubt if this issue is caused by another installed extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching this issue inside out (and vise versa), I have finally found out the reason for the mess described in the question here (at least for my specific case):

It appeared that I had a few versions of Visual Studio installed on my PC, which is obviously a very unhealthy situation to have. In my case, the only symptom for this kind of "sick" diversity that I have noticed was the problem with the extension. And a good thing that happened...

I just uninstalled ALL the versions I had installed on my PC and re-installed only the version (one of them) I wanted to continue working with (in my case, VS2013 Community).

I re-installed all the desired extensions, including of course the Productivity Power Tools, and everything is working just fine.

Of course, rebooting the system between installs wouldn't hurt...
After all, I am talking about a Windows-based PC. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Check it!

Tools - Options - Environment - Extension Manager - Load per user extensions...

Worked for me.

[image: Check this setting in Options]